# Kotlin: What is a kjsm file?

Tags: javascript, kotlin

I have been trying to use the Kotlin -> js compiler by following [this tutorial](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/javascript/getting-started-command-line/command-line-library-js.html).

When I run `kotlinc-js --help`, then the help text mentions the following:

```
-kjsm    Generate kjsm-files (for creating libraries)
```

What is a kjsm file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A **kjsm**-file is a **K**otlin **J**ava**S**cript **M**eta file (see [`KotlinJavaScriptMetaFileType`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/5db75c993bf98ee1f1d713544963ec67ff3367f9/idea/idea-analysis/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/idea/decompiler/js/KotlinJavaScriptMetaFileType.kt)).

Such a file appears to be used to provide meta data for native JavaScript objects so that the Kotlin compiler can type-check things and so that an IDE can provide code completion, etc. e.g. If you look in kotlin-js-library-1.0.6.jar you will find, among other kjsm-files, a `Window.kjsm` file which defines the [Window Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) available in web browsers.

You would want to generate your own kjsm-files whenever you are creating a library so that your interfaces can be used by the compiler/IDE in modules which depend on your Kotlin JavaScript library.

Comment: Ok, so it's basically for creating reusable libraries. That makes sense.

Comment: How to import this file in Intellij?